# New ZFS install, no pools available

Tags: 20.04, zfs

So I just installed Ubuntu 20.04 with ZFS.

First weird thing is that I believe it automatically created a mirrored install on my two identical drives, because linux Disks is showing a block device with both disks as part of it. That's fine, although I would have preferred to be in control of that...

The odd thing however is that zpool list is showing "no pools available".

I want to note that these used to be a hardware raid configuration and I did not clean up the disks. I just assumed the Ubuntu install procedure will wipe them as necessary.  I wonder if that's part of the issue.

Any idea what might have happened?

Here's the output of fdisk -l for the two disks:

```
Disk /dev/sda: 465.78 GiB, 500107862016 bytes, 976773168 sectors
Disk model: Samsung SSD 860 
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disklabel type: dos
Disk identifier: 0x2b65feb0

Device     Boot   Start       End   Sectors   Size Id Type
/dev/sda1          2048   1050623   1048576   512M  b W95 FAT32
/dev/sda2       1052670 975699967 974647298 464.8G  5 Extended
/dev/sda5       1052672 975699967 974647296 464.8G 83 Linux


Disk /dev/sdb: 465.78 GiB, 500107862016 bytes, 976773168 sectors
Disk model: Samsung SSD 860 
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disklabel type: dos
Disk identifier: 0x2b65feb0

Device     Boot   Start       End   Sectors   Size Id Type
/dev/sdb1          2048   1050623   1048576   512M  b W95 FAT32
/dev/sdb2       1052670 975699967 974647298 464.8G  5 Extended
/dev/sdb5       1052672 975699967 974647296 464.8G 83 Linux


Disk /dev/mapper/ddf1_4c53492020202020100000791000926047114711f44cec6f: 465.26 GiB, 499558383616 bytes, 975699968 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disklabel type: dos
Disk identifier: 0x2b65feb0

Device                                                             Boot   Start       End   Sectors   Size Id Type
/dev/mapper/ddf1_4c53492020202020100000791000926047114711f44cec6f1         2048   1050623   1048576   512M  b W95 FAT32
/dev/mapper/ddf1_4c53492020202020100000791000926047114711f44cec6f2      1052670 975699967 974647298 464.8G  5 Extended
/dev/mapper/ddf1_4c53492020202020100000791000926047114711f44cec6f5      1052672 975699967 974647296 464.8G 83 Linux
```

Here's the output of lsblk:

```
sda                                                          8:0    0 465.8G  0 disk   
    └─ddf1_4c53492020202020100000791000926047114711f44cec6f    253:0    0 465.3G  0 dmraid 
      ├─ddf1_4c53492020202020100000791000926047114711f44cec6f1 253:1    0   512M  0 part   /boot/efi
      ├─ddf1_4c53492020202020100000791000926047114711f44cec6f2 253:2    0     1K  0 part   
      └─ddf1_4c53492020202020100000791000926047114711f44cec6f5 253:3    0 464.8G  0 part   /
sdb                                                          8:16   0 465.8G  0 disk   
    └─ddf1_4c53492020202020100000791000926047114711f44cec6f    253:0    0 465.3G  0 dmraid 
      ├─ddf1_4c53492020202020100000791000926047114711f44cec6f1 253:1    0   512M  0 part   /boot/efi
      ├─ddf1_4c53492020202020100000791000926047114711f44cec6f2 253:2    0     1K  0 part   
      └─ddf1_4c53492020202020100000791000926047114711f44cec6f5 253:3    0 464.8G  0 part   /
```

Comment: Does `sudo zpool list` gives other/better result? zpool and zfs might need elevated privileges (root rights).

Comment: Yeah I tried that too.  I used sudo, also ran the command as root without any effect.

Comment: I just wanted to add a resolution to my question.  I re-installed it and now everything is fine.  I'm not sure what happened the first time.  It could have been a mistake and I may not have chosen the ZFS option and not noticed.